# Raspery Pi 3 OpenCL GPU Support?

Tags: opencl, signal-processing, fft

I want to use the raspery Pi for signal processing, so I asked myself how I get the FFT calculating very fast. 
My Idea is to use the GPU for the FFT. Old Idea but a working idea as I understanded.
My question is,
Does anyone has a clue about whether the new Raspery Pi 3 supports OpenCL and or other libarys for using GPU?

Edit:
Maybe there's a "vendor" for ARM GPU's like the open-source project for Intel GPU support on linux (Beignet)..

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that there is a way of running OpenCL on RPi. It is definitely possible to use GPU intrinsics for FFT.

Here is an [example of that](https://github.com/raspberrypi/userland/tree/master/host_applications/linux/apps/hello_pi/hello_fft).